# how does a JTree respond to a changed DefaultMutableTreeNode?

Tags: java, swing, jtree, treenode, event-dispatch-thread

Just trying to work out what happens, in terms of threads, if you change the user object of a DefaultMutableTreeNode in a non-EDT thread?

I'm not talking about the DefaultTreeModel events, namely insertNodeInto and removeNodeFromParent, which I'm pretty clear should always be run in the EDT... *I think...*

In the case of changes to nodes' user objects, it appears that JTree.TreeModelHandler is the thing which is "listening" for such events... but is there reason to expect that the listener will only be notified of such a change in the thread where the event happened?  And will propagate its response only in that self-same thread?

Obviously, therefore, I am assuming that this is a fairly basic "observer" pattern.

So does this mean that most changes in the nodes of a JTree must in fact be made to occur in the EDT, at the risk otherwise of things not happening as and when you expect?

In the API for DefaultMutableTreeNode it does indeed say that "you must do your own synchronizing"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Swing threading rules are very simple: Swing is single-threaded, and all operations involving Swing components should happen on the EDT.

So as soon as your `TreeModel` containing `DefaultMutableTreeNode`s is set on a `JTree` you better make sure any changes you make to the model (or the node's) and the corresponding events which are fired happen on the EDT.

Comment: `JTree` is particularly sensitive to this important principle; see also [Initial Threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: thanks... in a way I wonder why most/all JTree (and other JComponent) methods didn't therefore involve an "isEventDispatchThread()" test... and disallow non-EDT calls...

Comment: @mikerodent In JavaFX they took care of that. You can do this yourself by setting a custom repaint manager (see [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/alexfromsun/archive/2006/02/debugging_swing.html))

Comment: @Robin thanks, very useful link.  "We are going to make Swing debugging easier in Java 1.7".  Meanwhile will study what is said there about these 2 possible solutions.

Comment: @Robin I now use CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager... but I now don't really think that all actions for JTree and DefaultTreeModel (for example) must always occur in the EDT: if these objects are "offline" (i.e. not showing) it is perfectly OK, IMHO, to manipulate them in non-EDT threads.  You just have to be rigorous about when they are once again being handled by the EDT.  If you mess up the RepaintManager will usually catch you.  But I think a blanket imposition of EDT checking for all methods of all Swing objects limits perfectly legitimate designs involving "offline" manipulation.

Comment: @mikerodent As explained in that article it was previously allowed to create Swing components on another Thread, and there was a time where you were allowed to modify non-visible components on another thread as well. However, the current guidelines say that all creation and interaction with all swing components (also invisible ones) should happen on the EDT

Comment: @Robin apologies ... yes indeed... unfortunately the link to Oracle on A. Potochkin's interesting page which may one day have shown the rationale for this "blanket ban" is now broken.  Something like hot-swapping pre-prepared JTree-TreeModel combinations as the component of a JViewport is the kind of thing I have in mind. Works for me, but I'd like to know what the reasoning is behind this blanket ban...